# Python: creating a dictionary that writes high scores to a file

Tags: python, list, dictionary, pickle

First: you don't have to code this for me, unless you're a super awesome nice guy. But since you're all great at programming and understand it so much better than me and all, it might just be easier (since it's probably not too many lines of code) than writing paragraph after paragraph trying to make me understand it.

So - I need to make a list of high scores that updates itself upon new entries.  *So here it goes:*

**First step** - done

I have player-entered input, which has been taken as a data for a few calculations:

```
import time
import datetime

print "Current time:", time1.strftime("%d.%m.%Y, %H:%M")
time1 = datetime.datetime.now()
a = raw_input("Enter weight: ")    
b = raw_input("Enter height: ")
c = a/b
```

**Second step** - making high score list

Here, I would need some sort of a dictionary or a thing that would read the previous entries and check if the score (`c`) is (at least) better than the score of the last one in "high scores", and if it is, it would prompt you to enter your name.

After you entered your name, it would post your name, your `a`, `b`, `c`, and time in a high score list.

This is what I came up with, and it definitely doesn't work:

```
list = [("CPU", 200, 100, 2, time1)]
player = "CPU"
a = 200
b = 100
c = 2
time1 = "20.12.2012, 21:38"
list.append((player, a, b, c, time1))
list.sort()

import pickle
scores = open("scores", "w")
pickle.dump(list[-5:], scores)
scores.close()

scores = open("scores", "r")
oldscores = pickle.load(scores)
scores.close()
print oldscores()
```

I **know** I did something terribly stupid, but anyways, thanks for reading this and I hope you can help me out with this one. :-)

Comment: Your code is all out of order and duplicative.  You can't create `list` (which, btw, you shouldn't call that as `list` is a builtin) with `time1` because you don't initialize `time1` till 5 lines later.  And since you already have list, redeclaring all those values explicitly is just introducing a vector for bugs; if you need the values assigned to unique labels, unpack the tuple in `list`.  You also probably want to `open` and read in the old high scores in to `list` before adding and sorting in the new score, otherwise you will trample the existing scores list.

Comment: The title says dictionary, but there are no dictionaries here.

Comment: I now see I should've said a sorted list, not a dictionary, i'm a novice beginner. 

so i should make a open("..." "r") and then open("..." "w")

and all should be allright?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, don't use `list` as a variable name. It shadows the [built-in `list`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#list) object. Second, avoid using just plain date strings, since it is much easier to work with [`datetime`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) objects, which support proper comparisons and easy conversions.

Here is a full example of your code, with individual functions to help divide up the steps. I am trying not to use any more advanced modules or functionality, since you are obviously just learning:

```
import os
import datetime
import cPickle

# just a constants we can use to define our score file location
SCORES_FILE = "scores.pickle"

def get_user_data():
    time1 = datetime.datetime.now()
    print "Current time:", time1.strftime("%d.%m.%Y, %H:%M")

    a = None
    while True:
        a = raw_input("Enter weight: ")    
        try:
            a = float(a)
        except:
            continue
        else:
            break

    b = None
    while True:
        b = raw_input("Enter height: ")    
        try:
            b = float(b)
        except:
            continue
        else:
            break

    c = a/b

    return ['', a, b, c, time1]

def read_high_scores():
    # initialize an empty score file if it does
    # not exist already, and return an empty list
    if not os.path.isfile(SCORES_FILE):
        write_high_scores([])
        return []

    with open(SCORES_FILE, 'r') as f:
        scores = cPickle.load(f)
    return scores

def write_high_scores(scores):
    with open(SCORES_FILE, 'w') as f:
        cPickle.dump(scores, f)

def update_scores(newScore, highScores):
    # reuse an anonymous function for looking
    # up the `c` (4th item) score from the object
    key = lambda item: item[3]

    # make a local copy of the scores
    highScores = highScores[:]

    lowest = None
    if highScores:
        lowest = min(highScores, key=key)

    # only add the new score if the high scores
    # are empty, or it beats the lowest one
    if lowest is None or (newScore[3] > lowest[3]):
        newScore[0] = raw_input("Enter name: ")
        highScores.append(newScore)

    # take only the highest 5 scores and return them
    highScores.sort(key=key, reverse=True)
    return highScores[:5]

def print_high_scores(scores):
    # loop over scores using enumerate to also
    # get an int counter for printing
    for i, score in enumerate(scores):
        name, a, b, c, time1 = score
        # #1    50.0    jdi    (20.12.2012, 15:02)
        print "#%d\t%s\t%s\t(%s)" % \
            (i+1, c, name, time1.strftime("%d.%m.%Y, %H:%M"))


def main():
    score = get_user_data()
    highScores = read_high_scores()

    highScores = update_scores(score, highScores)

    write_high_scores(highScores)
    print_high_scores(highScores)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

What it does now is only add new scores if there were no high scores or it beats the lowest. You could modify it to always add a new score if there are less than 5 previous scores, instead of requiring it to beat the lowest one. And then just perform the lowest check after the size of highscores >= 5

Comment: HOLLY MOLLY you did a whole code and everything works great. 

Do you have a paypal account or something this thing is what I need. Yay for you wow

Comment: :-)  Well I wasn't going to write out the code, but I started seeing answers that were directing you towards more complicated solutions. I figured I better just write something up with a bunch of comments and keep it really really simple. And no I can't take your money. It's a free community! Enjoy.

Answer (score 2):

The first thing I noticed is that you did not tell `list.sort()` that the sorting should be based on the last element of each entry. By default, `list.sort()` will use Python's default sorting order, which will sort entries based on the first element of each entry (i.e. the name), then mode on to the second element, the third element and so on. So, you have to tell `list.sort()` which item to use for sorting:

```
from operator import itemgetter
[...]
list.sort(key=itemgetter(3))
```

This will sort entries based on the item with index 3 in each tuple, i.e. the fourth item.

Also, `print oldscores()` will definitely not work since `oldscores` is not a function, hence you cannot call it with the `()` operator. `print oldscores` is probably better.

Comment: I think the "score" is c, index 3 of the tuple. So I think `key=itemgetter(3)` is what the OP wants.

Comment: great, but you know I'm really new to python and programming at all and I don't know what your code even means.

like from operator import itemgetter

Comment: [...]
list.sort....

i just don't know what i'm supposed to do except correct the oldscores and list.sort().

Thanks for answers thogh

Comment: @academeniaan: You did ask for code to just be written without long explanations :-)

Comment: Yeah i know You bastard :D 

 But I still got this problem. How would I insert a human player if he "beats the score"? and How would I bautify my list a bit?

Because my file ATM looks pretty incomprehencable

Answer (score 1):

You definitely don't want a dictionary here. The whole point of a dictionary is to be able to map keys to values, without any sorting. What you want is a sorted list. And you've already got that.

Well, as Tamás points out, you've actually got a list sorted by the player name, not the score. On top of that, you want to sort in downward order, not upward. You could use the decorate-sort-undecorate pattern, or a key function, or whatever, but you need to do *something*. Also, you've put it in a variable named `list`, which is a very bad idea, because that's already the name of the `list` type.

Anyway, you can find out whether to add something into a sorted `list`, and where to insert it if so, using the [`bisect`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html) module in the standard library. But it's probably simpler to just use something like [`SortedCollection`](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577197-sortedcollection/) or [`blist`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/blist/).

Here's an example:

```
highscores = SortedCollection(scores, key=lambda x: -x[3])
```

Now, when you finish the game:

```
highscores.insert_right((player, a, b, newscore, time1))
del highscores[-1]
```

That's it. If you were actually not in the top 10, you'll be added at #11, then removed. If you were in the top 10, you'll be added, and the old #10 will now be #11 and be removed.

If you don't want to prepopulate the list with 10 fake scores the way old arcade games used to, just change it to this:

```
highscores.insert_right((player, a, b, newscore, time1))
del highscores[10:]
```

Now, if there were already 10 scores, when you get added, #11 will get deleted, but if there were only 3, nothing gets deleted, and now there are 4.

Meanwhile, I'm not sure why you're writing the new scores out to a `pickle` file, and then reading the same thing back in. You probably want to do the reading before adding the highscore to the list, and then do the writing after adding it.

You also asked how to "beautify the list". Well, there are three sides to that.

First of all, in the code, `(player, a, b, c, time1)` isn't very meaningful. Giving the variables better names would help, of course, but ultimately you still come down to the fact that when accessing list, you have to do `entry[3]` to get the score or `entry[4]` to get the time.

There are at least three ways to solve this:

- Store a `list` (or `SortedCollection`) of `dict`s instead of `tuple`s. The code gets a bit more verbose, but a lot more readable. You write `{'player': player, 'height': a, 'weight': b, 'score': c, 'time': time1}`, and then when accessing the list, you do `entry['score']` instead of `entry[3]`.
- Use a collection of [`namedtuple`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple)s.  Now you can actually just insert `ScoreEntry(player, a, b, c, time1)`, or you can insert `ScoreEntry(player=player, height=a, weight=b, score=c, time=time1)`, whichever is more readable in a given case, and they both work the same way. And you can access `entry.score` or as `entry[3]`, again using whichever is more readable.
- Write an explicit class for score entries. This is pretty similar to the previous one, but there's more code to write, and you can't do indexed access anymore, but on the plus side you don't have to understand `namedtuple`.

Second, if you just `print` the entries, they look like a mess. The way to deal with that is string formatting. Instead of `print scores`, you do something like this:

print '\n'.join("{}: height {}, weight {}, score {} at {}".format(entry)
                   for entry in highscores)

If you're using a `class` or `namedtuple` instead of just a `tuple`, you can even format by name instead of by position, making the code much more readable.

Finally, the highscore file itself is an unreadable mess, because `pickle` is not meant for human consumption. If you want it to be human-readable, you have to pick a format, and write the code to serialize that format. Fortunately, the CSV format is pretty human-readable, and most of the code is already written for you in the [`csv`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module. (You may want to look at the `DictReader` and `DictWriter` classes, especially if you want to write a header line. Again, there's the tradeoff of a bit more code for a lot more readability.)

Comment: Is there really a specific need to sort in descending when the OP can just continue to index from the end (myList[-5:])? `sort` also takes a `reverse=True` if it really did need to be backwards

Comment: @jdi: `bisect` doesn't take a `reverse`. Neither does `SortedCollection`. And no, you don't _need_ to sort in descending order, but the "delete the guy who falls off the end" gets more complicated, and it's just conceptually harder to think about `highscores` as an upside-down top 10 list than as a top 10 list.

Comment: Hi it appeares as though I can't use this SortedCollection "thing" that's messing around. Do I need to import a certain library first or something? Help out please

Comment: @academeniaan: To use a recipe from ActiveState like `SortedCollection`, you have to download it and either save it in a file you can import, or add it directly to your own file. I believe there's something on the recipe site explaining how to do that. (And to use a library from PyPI like `blist`, you need to `pip install blist`, and then you can import it.)

Comment: well I don't think this is going to cut it as I will have to make the program readily portable unfortunately. Just for the sake of imagination, let's just say a certain professor doesn't have time to do that in his time unfortunately, thanks though

Comment: @academeniaan: If you copy a recipe into your code, that doesn't made your code any less portable than if you'd written the code yourself. The compiler can't tell where the code came from, just what it says. (If you're worried about licenses, ActiveState recipes are legal to use just about any way you want—but code you find on StackOverflow may not be.)

Answer (score 1):

Here are the things I notice.

These lines seem to be in the wrong order:

```
print "Current time:", time1.strftime("%d.%m.%Y, %H:%M")
time1 = datetime.datetime.now()
```

When the user enters the height and weight, they are going to be read in as strings, not integers, so you will get a TypeError on this line:

```
c = a/b
```

You could solve this by casting a and b to float like so:

```
a = float(raw_input("Enter weight: "))
```

But you'll probably need to wrap this in a try/catch block, in case the user puts in garbage, basically anything that can't be cast to a float.  Put the whole thing in a while block until they get it right.

So, something like this:

```
b = None
while b == None:
    try:
        b = float(raw_input("Enter height: "))
    except:
        print "Weight should be entered using only digits, like '187'"
```

So, on to the second part, you shouldn't use `list` as a variable name, since it's a builtin, I'll use `high_scores`.

```
# Add one default entry to the list
high_scores = [("CPU", 200, 100, 2, "20.12.2012, 4:20")]
```

You say you want to check the player score against the high score, to see if it's best, but if that's the case, why a list?  Why not just a single entry?  Anyhow, that's confusing me, not sure if you really want a high score list, or just one high score.

So, let's just add the score, no matter what:

Assume you've gotten their name into the `name` variable.

```
high_score.append((name, a, b, c, time1))
```

Then apply the other answer from @Tamás

Comment: Hi, I definitely want a highscore list of like 3 or more guys, that make the entry. If that helps you any.

Comment: Then just sort the list like @Tamás mentions using itemgetter.  `high_score.sort(key=itemgetter(3))` then to trim the list to 5 people, do this:  `high_score = high_score[:5]`

Comment: Yeah so what Tamas did is the way to go and i ignore abarnert?

Comment: There are bits of goodness in both, but it looks like @jdi put together the comprehensive solution you'll want to use.